# Centrar ionic avatar

Tags: html, css, ionic

Estoy utilizando **ionic** y tengo un problema con el avatar. Deseo centrar el avatar en la pantalla pero no puedo.

```
<ion-avatar class="align-text-center">
    <img src="./assets/galeria/iconousuario.jpg" style="text-align: center">
</ion-avatar>
```

Comment: Agrega tu versión de ionic por favor. Pero por mi parte te aconsejo estudiar la grid de ionic para que no te compliques tanto con el css. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que no puedes aplicar la propiedad y valor `text-align: center;` a la etiqueta `img` ya que esta es un elemento `in-line` y dicha propiedad y valor de acuerdo con [la Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) solo funciona para elementos en bloque o una *table-cell box*.

Entonces dado que tienes una etiqueta `ion-avatar` pudieras hacer lo siguiente:

Aplica el `text-align: center;` a la antes mencionada ya que es la que contiene a la imagen embebida quedando así:

```
<style>
    ion-avatar{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

> Asumiendo que dicha etiqueta se comporte como bloque

O bien puedes decantarte por el uso de `flexbox` indicando que la etiqueta contenedora que es `ion-avatar` sea `flex` y haga flexibles a los elementos dentro de si, en este caso la etiqueta `img` quedando así:

```
<style>
    ion-avatar{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>
```

El código anterior a la etiqueta que contiene el elemento hará que todos aquellos dentro de, se alinen al centro.

En dado caso de que la etiqueta `ion-avatar` no se comporte como bloque, pudieras agregar un `div` que contenga a la `img` y con las mismas propuestas que ya te dí; esta vez solo deberías aplicar los estilos de cada propuesta pero a la etiqueta `div`

Comment: Estudia el grid de ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid

Answer (score 1):

Las anteriores respuestas no funcionaron, intenta con este style que a mi me funcionó:

```js
<ion-avatar style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <img src="./assets/galeria/iconousuario.jpg">
</ion-avatar>
```

O si quieres ponerlo en un css o scss para reutilizarlo en otros lugares sería algo como:

```js
<ion-avatar class="image-center">
    <img src="./assets/galeria/iconousuario.jpg">
</ion-avatar>
```

Y en el scss:

```css
.image-center{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó para mi

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
     <ion-avatar>
       <img src="./assets/galeria/iconousuario.jpg">
     </ion-avatar>
</div>
```